# Is it possible to use sonar/radar satellite at the furthest possible orbit of earth to detect incoming dangers? Does the math add up to be possible?

Tags: gravity

Does this theory have a  realistic outcome,and wouldn't radar work better in space? Would we be able to set up a system of detection satellites with the capabilities to detect incoming asteroids ect. In reasonable time? How many do we need?

Answer (score 1):

sonar will not work in space because there is no transmissive medium out there to carry sound waves. Radar works fine in space and has been used to study the surfaces of distant planets. radar can be used to detect incoming hazards like asteroids and comets, but to see them before they are already so close that flaming death is imminent requires a very powerful radar beam, which would require a power supply so big as to be impractical to put into orbit. this means the "early warning" radars you are interested in would probably have to be built and operated on the ground and not in orbit. the number of ground-based radars required to cover all of the sky depends on how powerful each of them is and over what range of angles each of them can be steered; the minimum number would be between four and six.

However, note that optical telescopes can also be used to search for asteroids which might swing close enough to pose a collision hazard with the earth. in fact, optical telescope searches for "near earth" objects like asteroids have already been going on for many years.

Answer (score 0):

Radars are mostly not used to find NEOs (near earth objects - asteroids and comets) that can be potentially hazardous to the earth. It's optical and infrared telescopes that are used. It would take very large radar antennas. All NEO searching telescopes are currently earth based except one, but more space based telescopes dedicated to this earth are assumed. The study considered present detection assets, and possible near term technology improvements (aperture sizes increases by a factor of 10 or so in area, improved device light or IR sensing sensitivities, and improved search methods with sequential detection).

Asteroids and comets that can be hazardous need not be very large (see sizes below) and need to be detected far enough away (see below, far enough can provide a few days or weeks or warning, or longer warning to plan a mission against it), and their track estimated well enough to determine if they will come with 1.3 AUs (astronomical units, distance sun-earth). That is then 0.3 AUs posible distance to earth, or 30 million miles. Not all NEOs are potentially hazardous objects (PHOs), where their orbits are such that they will come within .05 AUs and may impact the earth, but without determining the orbit more accurately they become possible PHOs.

There are roughly about 25000 (statistically estimated) NEOs that are bigger than 460 ft in size, and those and bigger are the potentially dangerous objects. From about 100 ft to 460 ft they will typically reach the surface of the earth (i.e., not burn up in the atmosphere), but only have more or less local effects. At 460 ft and up they can have regional and global effects. At sizes of 1km and bigger sizes they can be globally catastrophic to the earth. There's an estimated 1000 1 km and larger

See some of the facts in tHe NASA FAQ on the topic. It looks like its firm about 2015 or 2016. See it at https://www.nasa.gova/planetarydefense/faq
There is a more recent NASA report from Sept 2017 at https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/2017_neo_sdt_final_e-version.pdf

The NEO objects need to be detected far enough away, and then their track estimated to determine if they will reach the 30 million mile NEO definition, and even if they are PHOs. Thus an NEO is not one within 30 million miles, but one that could come within that range. It takes some observation time on their far orbits to estimate their tracks well enough to gets the orbital parameters. Most or all NEOs are objects orbiting the Sun at some distances, and originated from the main asteroid belt in collisions or breakups. The whole analysis is more complex as it takes into account probabilities of detection and as function of object magnitude, which is correlated but not 1-1 with object size. It goes deeper also considering possible asteroid makeup.

The NASA study analyzes two end result cases, one for cataloguing the NEOs and one for getting a warning of an impact. The warning would be enough to evacuate areas, but not to avoid the impact by altering the object's orbit (or destroying it). Cataloguing would allowed us to know about 99% of possible NAEs in the next hundred years or so, allowing for possible orbit changing countermeasures.

Radars can not detect these objects at distances of a few AUs for the weeks warning, or further away for a catalogue that allows years in doing a mission.  You can use the radar range equation below, and plug in numbers to get SNR = Pr/Noise Power, and see if you can get to the few dB needed for detection. You can look up the equation in Wikipedia. It's main drawbacks are two: 1) the power returned goes like $1/R^4$, whereas optical or IR detection is the usual $1/R^2$, and 2)wavelengths are much smaller at optical and IR and so apertures can be smaller, on the order of 1-10 meters. It'll be larger for radars. You can use the radar range equation to get numbers for possible SNRs and noise figures. I've not done the numbers in this case, but that's the way to do it.